# I have been accused of sending porn to my fiance's ex

Tags: ip

I have not, but she says that she has my IP addres, which I know can be spoofed and also can be found out by my email header. What can I do to combat this liar?

I have a hotmail account and she has a yahoo account. I have tried to get the Html info, but no matter what I try it says that I do not have the right information. Please tell me how she made this information up, as I never sent her any pornographic material.

Comment: You should be talking to a lawyer.

Comment: First, IP addresses cannot be spoofed in the way you are thinking. Second, without the original headers from the email, there is nothing you can prove.

Comment: Is porn a crime where you live?  If not, why give a rat's ass? I'd send her some porn just because it's funny when people freak out over it.

Comment: @cHao a) Yes, obscenity can be illegal. b) Yes, sending obscene images to someone who does not wish to receive them can well be considered harassment, which can be a crime. c) If you have ongoing legal proceedings and are illegally harassing the other party, you can expect legal consequences.

Comment: @cpast: If the other party wants to do anything in court, then they have to come up off some evidence. And if Gina's innocent, then there is no such evidence, and the other party will be even more obviously the one causing trouble.

Answer (score 3):

I feel for you.

We are a bunch of tech nerds, not lawyers, which is what you need by the sounds of it. Any good IT lawyer will be able to give you information that's at least as good as what we can.

What I *can* offer is a nerdy analysis of email headers . You should get your lawyer to demand a copy of that supposed porn email from her so you can inspect the header yourself. Have your lawyer subpoena a copy directly from Yahoo's mail server, mind you, not a printout that she could have doctored.

The very first thing to check is that the email in question *actually didn't come from your account*. It's possible that someone has your password. Check your outbox, etc. If this is the case, Hotmail may be able to provide login histories to tell you the IP address that was logged in at that time, either through the regular site, or through a subpoena.

Yes, email headers are easy to spoof, but if you compare the one she's claiming you sent against an email you actually did send, you might find some telling differences. Some things you can look for are (disclaimer, I am not an information forensics guy, but some on this site are, so please correct me) -- the example below is an [example header](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/29436?hl=en) of an email from `MrJones@emailprovider.com` to `MrSmith@gmail.com` :

- Sender's IP Address and mail server

  Received: from mail.emailprovider.com (mail.emailprovider.com [111.111.11.111]) by mx.gmail.com

Spoofing the *From: address* is easy, my understanding is that spoofing the sever and IP address is harder (if I'm wrong, please tell me in comments). Check this against other emails you've sent.

- Mail User Agents

The general format of an email header varies by provider (ie Yahoo with generate a different style of header than Hotmail). If the format of the header is not the same as on other mails you've sent, then this could be an argument that you didn't send it.

- timestamps

check the timestamps in the header to make sure the `sent` and `received` dates line up with her story.

Comment: Also: sending porn? That's the best she can come up with? Not sending an angry rant, or something more plausible?

Comment: "It's possible that someone has your password" including her ex.